# Update table using like operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables
table 1

```
Diagnosis            GroupID
155.0 - blaaaaaa      GAS
```

table 2

```
Code  GroupID  
155.0   
155.0
155.0
155.0
```

I did try to update GroupID  of second table from first

```
update Table2 set GroupID= GroupID from table 1 where Diagnosis like '%'+Code+'%'
```

but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would help, http://rextester.com/NILBI39557

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
Diagnosis   VARCHAR(255)
,GROUPID VARCHAR(255)
);

Insert Into Table1 Values('155.0 - blaaaaaa','GAS');

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
Code      VARCHAR(255)
,GROUPID VARCHAR(255)
);

Insert Into Table2 VALUES ('155.0', NULL);
Insert Into Table2 VALUES ('155.0', NULL);
Insert Into Table2 VALUES ('155.0', NULL);
Insert Into Table2 VALUES ('155.0', NULL);

SELECT * FROM Table2;

UPDATE T2 
SET    T2.GroupId = T1.GroupId
FROM   Table1 as T1 INNER JOIN Table2 as T2
ON     T1.Diagnosis LIKE '%'+T2.Code+'%';

SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

Comment: This _would_ help, except I posted an identical query nearly ten minutes before you posted this.  Would you claim that you did not see my answer before you posted?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not here to earn anything, I was working on another tab and i pasted my answer later though it showed `Load new answer`. I know you must be having good knowledge but I'm not here to claim anything. I've upvoted your answer, Enjoy.Thanks. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

Your current syntax for an update join is slightly off.  Try using this instead:

```
UPDATE t2
SET GroupID = t1.GroupID
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1
    ON t1.Diagnosis LIKE '%' + t2.Code + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
UPDATE 
Tb2 SET Tb2.GroupId = Tb1.GroupId
FROM table1 as Tb1 INNER JOIN table2 as Tb2
ON Tb1.Diagnosis LIKE '%'+Tb2.Code+'%';
```